# Install Microsoft Excel 2016 via Office 365

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365

I have just created an Office 365 account [for students](https://products.office.com/en-us/student/office-in-education). I can access all the apps online, but I also want Office installed for offline use on my PC.

If I go to https://portal.office.com/OLS/MySoftware.aspx to install the software, it seems I can only install Sharepoint Designer 2013 and OneDrive 2013, but I cannot find Excel, Word, etc.

I have read that the Office programs are part of Office 365, but if I try to install Excel separately, it seems I still need to pay.

Comment: Check in with your school admin.  There are options that can get you access to the installed versions for free, but it depends on how the school is enrolled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free service only includes the [online version](https://products.office.com/en-us/student/office-in-education)

> The service includes Office Online (Word, PowerPoint, Excel, and
>   OneNote), 1TB of OneDrive storage, Yammer, and SharePoint sites.

If your school enroll in additional program to provide you with the offline Office apps, you'll have the button to install Office.

> Some schools allow teachers and students to install the full Office
>   applications on up to 5 PCs or Macs for free. If your school provides
>   this additional benefit, you'll see the Install Office button on your
>   Office 365 home page after you complete sign-up.